# Display the same line of code on a different level on Python

Tags: python, ide, spyder

In RSweave in RStudio, you can have long lines breaking into multiple levels once they reach the end of the window, like this. Is this possible in the Spyder IDE (anaconda3)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To have the same behavior in Spyder, you need to go the menu

```
Tools > Preferences > Editor > Display
```

and activate the option called `Wrap lines`.